# Safari mobile menu is not working

Tags: jquery, safari

I don't have an iPhone but I have been told that the mobile menu does not work.  I have tried to fix this but really not getting anywhere.

There are other comments online in regards to this but no real solution was being represented.

here is a code pen. I have removed the "margin" and used a simple display:none; then display:block; and also "bind" and "on" but still no change.

Thank you for your help.

```
$('#menu-icon').click(function() {
  if($("nav").hasClass('navclick')){
       $("nav").removeClass('navclick')
   }else{
      $("nav").addClass('navclick')
   }

});
```

https://codepen.io/damates/pen/dmejej

Ys

Comment: That's strange. I tried on my iPhone X and menu worked. Try replacing "click" function to "on" with event click like $('#menu-icon').on("click", function(){ ... });

Comment: reported to still not work. http://www.ahimsainvestments.com in the main section and read more for golden visa

Comment: Also tried "bind" but with no luck.